# How to use TextBlob.correct() for a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, nlp, textblob, spelling

I'm trying to apply spelling correction to some tweets.

I have tried the following code: 
`train.text.apply(lambda x: " ".join([TextBlob(i).correct() for i in x.split()]))`

However, I get an error. Could you please advise? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to update this code with

`train.apply(lambda x: " ".join([TextBlob(i).correct() for i in x['text'].split()]))`

Hope this helps!!